# Adding a header to the right hand top corner from a specific page

Tags: positioning, header-footer

This is how my page looks:

[image]

What I want to do is, add a header to the blackened portion in this image:

[image]

These are the settings that I am already using:

```
\documentclass[letter, 10pt]{report}\normalsize
\usepackage{amsmath,utopia}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{needspace}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\textwidth 7.5in
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.75in}
\textheight 9.5in
\pagestyle{plain}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.73cm}
\topskip 0in
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\newenvironment{boxedlaw}[1]
  {\begin{Sbox}\begin{minipage}{#1}\centering}
  {\end{minipage}\end{Sbox}\begin{center}\fbox{\TheSbox}\end{center}}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\opencutright


\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{brown}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=3pt,rounded corners=0pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (0.4in,-0.4in) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.4in,0.4in) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{F8E0E0}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{0.5pc}
  {{\color{brown}\titlerule[2pt]}\vspace{0.1pc}\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}{}{0.5pc}
  {\MakeUppercase}
```

The header will be some static text. Not section names or page numbers. However I want it to start from the point I want. That is, I dont want that header on the first few pages. And I want it on every page after that. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I want to propose another solution, using the [titleps](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) package; the basic idea is to define a new page style which I called `special`; using `\pagestyle{special}` this new page style can be activated; since you also want to include the special text in the first page of some chapter(s), a redefinition of the plain style is also needed. Using `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`, the changes can be kept local (so you can apply the new style only to some page(s)). The code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,utopia}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{needspace}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\textwidth 7.5in
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.75in}
\textheight 9.5in
\pagestyle{plain}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.73cm}
\topskip 0in
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\newenvironment{boxedlaw}[1]
  {\begin{Sbox}\begin{minipage}{#1}\centering}
  {\end{minipage}\end{Sbox}\begin{center}\fbox{\TheSbox}\end{center}}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\opencutright


\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{brown}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=3pt,rounded corners=0pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (0.4in,-0.4in) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.4in,0.4in) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{F8E0E0}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{0.5pc}
  {{\color{brown}\titlerule[2pt]}\vspace{0.1pc}\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}{}{0.5pc}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example
\usepackage{titleps}

% command to store the fixed text that will go in the header
\newcommand\SpecialText{\raisebox{-1em}{Some fixed text}}

% definition of the new special page style to include the fixed text
\newpagestyle{special}
  {\sethead{}{}{\SpecialText}\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}

\begin{document}


\begingroup% to keep the change local
\pagestyle{special}
% since the first page of a chapter internally uses the plain page style
% we locally redefine this style to include the fixed text
\renewpagestyle{plain}
  {\sethead{}{}{\SpecialText}\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]
\endgroup% to keep the change local

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

And an image showing the special text in the first page of a chapter:

[image]

If you want to apply the `special` style to a single page different from the first page of a chapter, you can simply invoke

```
\thispagestyle{special}
```

somewhere in the material that will go in that page.

Comment: The problem I have when I use this is, this new pagestyle removes the page numbering on the page where a particular chapter starts. I want the page numbers to be displayed too. Also is there anything I can do to make sure that the text I write on the top right corner can be made to touch the upper margin?

Comment: @HarishKumar, I tried your way but I dont get anything. I dont understand. It displays the page as it was earlier.

Comment: @KaranThakkar: see my updated answer.

Comment: I get the page numbers now. No sweat. But another problem has come up. I dont know why but after page 45 in my manuscript the header text just stops appearing. Is there a page limit till which this solution works? This is the tex file. I did not know what code to include so you can see for yourself. http://db.tt/v2H1F2fB

Comment: @KaranThakkar: you have an "intruding" `flushleft` environment; carefully delete (or comment out) the  `\begin{flushleft}` (aprox. on line 177) and the `\end{flushleft}` (aprox. on line 1107), and reprocess your document.

Comment: Thank you so much @GonzaloMedina

I had one more query. Now that you have seen the tex file. Is there any easier way I can change the margin on the left side to 1 inch without having to change all the parboxes that I have defined in my code?

Comment: @KaranThakkar: Your welcome. Regarding the other issue, I don't see an easy way since your `\parbox`es have a hard-coded width.

Comment: Actually I added the parboxes because I was under the impression that Latex doesnt justify paragraphs by default. So now if I remove every parbox, is there any way to do it @GonzaloMedina ?

Comment: @KaranThakkar You can use the `geometry` package (which you are already loading) to do modifications to the page layout.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3178/discussion-between-karan-thakkar-and-gonzalo-medina)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not complete and minimal. However, the feature requested can be achieved `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} %<-----provides dummy text, remove in your file
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry} % <-----remove showframe and alter other things in your file
%---------------------------------------------
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{}   % Clear all headers and footers first
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[draw=brown,very thick,outer color=magenta!30,inner color=white, rectangle, rounded corners=.3cm] at ([xshift=-4.5cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) {My text comes here};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
%\setlength{\headsep}{1.1in} % if needed you can change this value
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}%
%Change the values in xshift and yshift as per your needs
%---------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\lipsum[6-8]
\end{document}
```

The pages with no header:

[image]

Pages with header:

[image]

You may tweak this style to suit your text and taste.